# C# - Path string to an embedded resource (Not for retrieval) for use in GUI test

Tags: c#, resources, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to perform a GUI test on application, a subsection of which is an attachment upload. Since there are a variety of use-cases, I'm trying to simply create a small range of attachments, the path for which can be simply entered into the GUI. With this, I can use a common attachments resource folder with just a few different types of attachments, which can be used globally.

i.e: `Resources.Attachments.TestAttachment.xlsx`

I'm having a tough time trying to find the path in the executing assembly. I don't need a stream as I don't need to access it, I simply need the path. I want to avoid making a temp file if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
using System.Reflection;
var resPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As far as I know, this simply gets you an array of the resources within the entire tree. No filepaths and no filtration by folder?